# Using SSH to push to 2 different repos using the same account?

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh

I have two repositories on one machine on the same account on Github. I've added an ssh key to my account and pushing to repository A succeeds but I can't push to repository B. SSH keys on github aren't associated to specific repos iirc.

A little research has led me to find out that I need two different keys. How do I edit my config file so that git uses the correct key when pushing to the second repo?

Comment: You don't need 2 keys.  What error are you getting?

Comment: Permission denied (publickey). But pushing to repo A works fine

Comment: Make sure two repos are under the same account. Can you attach the output of `git ls-remote --get-url origin` for both of your repos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to the solution by modifying the .ssh/config file to append this

```
Host repo2.github.com
  User git
  Port 22
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa2
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

and then adding by appending the following in the .git/config file

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@repo2.github.com:[Username]/G2-FrontEnd.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```